# Laravel 5 Illuminate\Http\Request has method not allowing static call

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to call the Illuminate\Http\Request has method from one of my controllers.

```
Request::has('fields')
```

Following from the documentation exactly, yet I'm getting an error thrown:

*Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::has() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context*

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I tried following the documentation as closely as possible.

Comment: As of Laravel 5, this is the correct approach/explanation http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574016/165084

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem is you are using the wrong `Request` class. You need to import the Facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

Comment: Thank you!  They should really update the documentation to explain this.

_Using a few simple methods, you may access all user input from your Illuminate\Http\Request instance. You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb used for the request, as input is accessed in the same way for all verbs._

Comment: You're welcome. Yes that's true. However you actually don't even need to import any class since there is an alias registered in `app.php`. However IDEs don't really get that. [This package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) helps though

Answer (score 3):

The use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request; is using the Facade which is not good practice. should use Illuminate\Http\Request; and get the request available via the method or constructor ie.-

```
public function __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
}
```

and then in the method use it, ie.

```
public function checkText() {
   $txt = $this->request->has('txt'); 
   return $txt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Input::has() instead then use Input::get() to actually grab the corresponding POSTED/GET var.